# Fallback behavior when an XSLT extension function is not present

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to provide fallback behavior when a function implemented in an external XSLT object is not present (in XSLT 1.0)?

Right now, I have something similar to

```
<xsl:template match="an-element">
  <xsl:value-of select="external-ns:ExternalFunction(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

However, it's possible to generate content that makes sense if `external-ns` is not available, it just won't be as smart. So, I'd like to have something like

```
<!-- (pseudo) -->
<xsl:template match="an-element">
  <xsl:try>
    <xsl:value-of select="external-ns:ExternalFunction(.)" />
    <xsl:catch>
      <!-- do something else with the node -->
    </xsl:catch>  
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm aware of `xsl:fallback` and `element-available()` but these seem to be only for elements, not functions. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-function-available

> **Function**: *boolean* **function-available**(*string*)
>
> The argument must evaluate to a string
>   that is a QName. The QName is expanded
>   into an expanded-name using the
>   namespace declarations in scope for
>   the expression. The function-available
>   function returns true if and only if
>   the expanded-name is the name of a
>   function in the function library. If
>   the expanded-name has a non-null
>   namespace URI, then it refers to an
>   extension function; otherwise, it
>   refers to a function defined by XPath
>   or XSLT.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed this. Thanks!